# Silverlight: Threads / Delayed Actions / Asynchronous invocations/events

Tags: silverlight, multithreading, events, asynchronous

I've got the following scenario: when a user moves the mouse out of a popup, I want an animation to happen, and five seconds later, I want to remove a PopUp.

This is the code I expected to do this with is:

```
private bool leftPopup = false;
public void AnimatePopupOut(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   myAnim.Begin();
   (new Thread(new ThreadStart(delayedRemovePopup))).Start();
}

private void delayedRemovePopup()
{
   leftPopup = true;
   Thread.Sleep(5000);
   PopUp.IsOpen = false;
}
```

The first line, "leftPopup = true" is fine, but the third, "PopUp.IsOpen = false" gives me an access violation exception, probably because this object belongs to the GUI thread. Is there any way I can gain access to the PopUp.IsOpen property? If not, is there another way that I can call an event after some time to do this?

Cheers

Nik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the PopUp.Dispatcher.Invoke(). That will marshal your call back to the UI thread.

Comment: Thank you very much for that suggestion. Instead of the thread clause I used "Action a = new Action(delayedRemovePopup);           PopUp.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(a);" and that solved it all. :-) Thanks a bunch!

Comment: FYI you don't need a temporary variable, just call Popup.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delayedRemovePopup);

Answer (score 1):

Here is a trick I did in WPF.  It is ported for use in Silverlight and hangs off of the Dispacher class.  I don't know about Maurice's answer because I don't see a "Invoke" method in SL5.  I do see the BeginInvoke, which is about usless when it comes to delayed actions.

Usage: You must include the System.Windows namespace in your code file or this extension method won't appear.

```
// lets say you want to enable a control 1 second after a save event
// lets say you just want to prevent click happy users from going crazy
//   This code assumes you disabled the button on the click event
Button b = this.idButton1;
b.Dispatcher.DelayInvoke(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), () => { b.Enabled = true; });
```

That is it.  Just one line of code does the trick.   Below is the extension class that makes the above code possible.

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace System.Windows {

    public static class DispatcherExtensions {

        public static void DelayInvoke<TArg1, TArg2, TArg3>(this Dispatcher dispatcher, TimeSpan delay, Action<TArg1, TArg2, TArg3> action, TArg1 arg1, TArg2 arg2, TArg3 arg3) {
            dispatcher.DelayInvoke(delay, (Delegate)action, arg1, arg2, arg3);
        }

        public static void DelayInvoke<TArg1, TArg2>(this Dispatcher dispatcher, TimeSpan delay, Action<TArg1, TArg2> action, TArg1 arg1, TArg2 arg2) {
            dispatcher.DelayInvoke(delay, (Delegate)action, arg1, arg2);
        }

        public static void DelayInvoke<TArg1>(this Dispatcher dispatcher, TimeSpan delay, Action<TArg1> action, TArg1 arg1) {
            dispatcher.DelayInvoke(delay, (Delegate)action, arg1);
        }

        public static void DelayInvoke(this Dispatcher dispatcher, TimeSpan delay, Action action) {
            dispatcher.DelayInvoke(delay, (Delegate)action);
        }

        public static void DelayInvoke(this Dispatcher dispatcher, TimeSpan delay, Delegate del, params object[] args) {

            if (dispatcher == null)
                throw new NullReferenceException();
            if (delay < TimeSpan.Zero)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("delay");
            if (del == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("del");

            var task = new Task(() => { Thread.Sleep(delay); });

            task.ContinueWith((t) => { dispatcher.BeginInvoke(del, args); });
            task.Start();
        }
    }
}
```